# Object property looking different after printing on it's own

Tags: javascript, date, time, luxon

I am trying to use luxon to generate a new date using a timezone. This is my code:

```
var luxon = require('luxon');
luxon.Settings.defaultZoneName = 'UTC+4';
var date = luxon.DateTime.local();
console.log(date);
var now = new Date(date.ts);
console.log(now.toString());
```

And this is the console:

```
DateTime {
    ts: 2018-09-13T13:09:45.333+04:00,
        zone: UTC+4,
        locale: en-US }
Thu Sep 13 2018 11:09:45 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

But if I try to access the `ts` property like so

```
var date = luxon.DateTime.local();
console.log(date.ts); // here
var now = new Date(date.ts);
console.log(now.toString());
```

I get this in the console:

```
1536830052009
Thu Sep 13 2018 11:14:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Why is that? Is it doing some kind of math in the background? Also it turns out this `date.ts` is just ignoring my timezone. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `1536830052009`, This is your time in milliseconds,

```
new Date(1536830052009)
// output Thu Sep 13 2018 11:14:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

You may want to check your timezone with [`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)

> Returns the time difference between UTC time and local time, in minutes

Many people use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to play with Date, I know it is not in your question but maybe you could find some usefull things

Comment: Yes it is. But the thing is I am trying to push the time by 4 hours ahead compared to my time. Also why is it different after logging as a property, if when logging the whole object?

Comment: This is because `2018-09-13T13:09:45.333+04:00`, is in Date format, try to cast it with `Date(date.ts)` and it will output it as you expect

Comment: How is it different from this? `var now = new Date(date.ts);`

Comment: It's not different, those are the same thing

Comment: That's why it's confusing. Do you see something wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't get where is your problem, your code works perfectly fine

Comment: It doesn't set the time 4 hours ahead. I think

Comment: Ok then you can do sometthing like `now.setHours(now.getHours() + 4);`

Answer (score 0):

`ts` is not a public property and you shouldn't use it. Luxon does all sorts of tricks under the covers to get the math right. If you want the timestamp, just use `date.toMillis()`. If you want a JS Date, use `date.toJSDate()`.

Two other important things to know:

1. It's not ignoring your zone. The zone doesn't change the time. It's more like metadata about a time that affects how we display it. The Luxon docs [cover this](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html#luxon-works-with-time-zones) a bit. You shouldn't expect to extract a different timestamp by fiddling with the zone. Now is always now.
2. Remember that the native Date object doesn't support timezones other than your local one. So anytime you convert from a Luxon object to a native Date, that information is lost. The time itself will be the same (meaning, it will represent the same millisecond), but it will express it in the local time.